# How do I access the G Suite Directory API from App Engine Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-workspace, service-accounts

I'm trying to follow the documentation, but I've been unable to actually get access. Ideally I'd like to use the app engine service account to access the user list for my domain, but I'd settle for using a separate service account.

1. I've created a service account. 
   **Email:** `myapp-gsuite-prod@mydomain-myapp-3.iam.gserviceaccount.com` 
   **ID:** `1097...8840`
2. The service account is enabled for G Suite Domain-wide Delegation.
   **Client ID:** `1097...8840`
3. In my domain under Security > API Controls > Domain-wide Delegation I've added this service account.
   **Client ID:** `1097...8840`
   **Scopes:** `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly`

---

### Trying with an implicit service account

I'm trying this approach because I'm hoping that I can use this same approach to get access for the App Engine service account.

```
$ export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/key.json"
$ python3
>>> import googleapiclient.discovery 
>>> userapi = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1')
>>> userapi.users().list(domain='my-domain.com', maxResults=100).execute()

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting 
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=my-domain.com.com&maxResults=100&alt=json
returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

---

### Trying with explicit service credentials

Here I'm actually loading the credentials instead of relying on `googleapiclient.discovery.build` to infer them from the environment:

```
$ python3
>>> SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly']
>>> SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '/path/to/key.json'
>>> from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
>>> import googleapiclient.discovery 
>>> credentials = Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
>>> userapi = googleapiclient.discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
>>> userapi.users().list(domain='my-domain.com', maxResults=100).execute()

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting 
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=my-domain.com.com&maxResults=100&alt=json
returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api">
```

---

I've also tried without the `domain='my-domain.com` bit. That gives me this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting 
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?maxResults=100&alt=json 
returned "Bad Request">
```

So I'm pretty sure the request is getting to the API. I'm unclear about why the access is denied.

Comment: Hi @Paul considering this similar case [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1884), it seems that the service account needs the role `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.security`. Could you please give it a try giving this role to the service account?

Comment: please note that you have to [add scope googleapis.com/auth/admin](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#scope-response). also, you can refer to [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) for concept and explanations.

Comment: @gso_gabriel Adding that scope both on the client and in the G Suite admin doesn't help. To get unblocked I started sending the subject as a super admin, which gave me the data I need. I read through the issue you linked and found that this was the resolution that seemed to work for most people, but this still feels like an error.

Comment: Sure, I understand. I believe that's why the issue on Github is still open, for the investigation/assistance to continue. Do you mind if I post as answer the link and clarification that I provided, including what you did? You can also post yourself, just so we have an answer for similar cases to assist the Community.

Comment: of course, that's fine

Comment: Hi @Paul , thanks for that! I have posted as Community Wiki, due to the fact that the solution was found/confirmed by you. Please, consider accepting it, so the Community knows that it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as Community Wiki, as it was based in the comments.

To solve this issue, while it's still being investigated/checked by the developers - more information in this Github issue [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/1884) - you will need to add your Service Account to more roles, to be able to access the G Suite Directory API from App Engine Python. You will need to start sending the subject as a super admin, so you don't face the permission issue anymore. This is based in comments from the linked issue.